# How to create/write a file using exp() in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line

in mysql prompt i want try to create/write a file using following command :

```
mysql> select exp(~(select*from(select 'hello')x)) into outfile '/home/febri/meh.txt';
```

but I get an error :

ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/febri/meh.txt' (Errcode: 13)

in addition to the above command is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are using EXP() doesn't have anything at all to do with the error. The problem is purely a permission issue. You are tring to write to `/home/febri/meh.txt` *as the mysql user*. But mysql user cannot access your home directory. Use /tmp/meh.txt instead.

```
select exp(~(select*from(select 'hello')x)) into outfile '/tmp/meh.txt';
```

Comment: It's worked!, but when I check why the file contents of the file 0?

Comment: run the query without into outfile and see if it produces any rows

Comment: create/write file is working but i get the following error : ERROR 1690 (22003): DOUBLE value is out of range in 'exp(~((select `x`.`hello` from (select 'hello' AS `hello`) `x`)))'

Comment: As for the query error, please be so kind as to post another question giving only the query (without the outfile part) and please do explain what your query is supposed to do. thanks and all the best

Comment: Did you post your question about the EXP() query? I will be happy to try to answer if I can